# Pseudoclasses :before and :after doesn't stick to element on some browsers

Tags: html, css

i got a problem with pseudoclass :before and :after, i want to stick element to the bottom of parent class by using position: absolute and top/bottom etc. I tried this:

```
#intro{
    background: url('../img/bg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
#intro:before{
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 0px 350px 200px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent rgb(255, 255, 255) transparent transparent;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
#intro:after{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 0px 350px 200px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgb(255, 255, 255) transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
}
```

but as you can see on the photo below it moves a bit over that, on standard android browser it works how it should. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MucqH.jpg)
Is there any solution to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you want to position an absolute element relative to its parent, you need to set the parent's position property to relative or absolute. Thus, right now your `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements are being positioned relative to the body, not the `#intro` element. Also trying a margin/padding reset never hurts in diagnosing problems like this:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#intro {
  position: relative;
}
```

Good luck!